# Cannot run express-spdy app using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, spdy

I'm not able to run NodeJS Express-Spdy examples downloaded from GitHub.
I'm getting the below error:

```
 C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\express-spdy>node app.js

 module.js:340
 throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'express-spdy'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\express-  spdy\app.js:6:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

Please tell me how to resolve this error, as I have put express-spdy inside node_modules folder.

When I run the example using SPDY module only by placing it inside node_modules it works fine but with express-spdy module it shows above error.

Comment: It's very confusing your question. Please rephrase it.

Comment: I am trying to learn how the client and server communicates in node js using SPDY and found this express-spdy to start with. I have also checked the node-spdy from github and able to run 2 examples from that code. If you have any reference to start building node JS SPDY server and client please let me know

Comment: Install it via npm `npm install express-spdy` preferably some place in your user directory. Dont copy paste stuff inside Program Files to make it work.

Comment: Maybe try: https://npmjs.org/package/spdy instead? Seems to have a lot of traction.